# how to change value of matrix with for loop using another matrix in r?

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, matrix

I have two matrix; m1 and m2

```
m1:
  a  b  c  d  e
x 0  0  0  0  0
y 0  0  0  0  0
x 0  0  0  0  0


m2:
  y
a 1.2
c 1.5
e 1.4
```

here is my code;

```
 for (i in 1:4){
   if colnames(m1[i]) in rownanmes(m2[i])
        m1["y", i] == m2[i]
 }
```

so far i got this matrix,

```
  a    b    c    d  e
x 0    0    0    0  0
y 1.2  1.5  1.4  NA NA
x 0    0    0    0  0
```

but I want to create matrix like this ;

```
  a    b  c    d  e
x 0    0  0    0  0
y 1.2  0  1.5  0  1.4
x 0    0  0    0  0
```

Any suggestion? thanks

Comment: Could you provide that full `dput` output of `m1` instead of `...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to do:

```
indx <- Map(intersect, dimnames(t(m2)), dimnames(m1))
m1[indx[[1]], indx[[2]]] <- m2[indx[[2]], indx[[1]]]
m1
#    a b   c d   e
#x 0.0 0 0.0 0 0.0
#y 1.2 0 1.5 0 1.4
#x 0.0 0 0.0 0 0.0
```

#### Update

Based on the `dput` output of `m2` (in the comments), the colname of `m2` is `m2` and because there are no intersects between the rownames of `m1` and colname of `m2`, when you use the code, it will not replace anything.

```
 m1[indx[[1]], indx[[2]]] <- m2[indx[[2]], indx[[1]]]
 m1
 #  a b c d e
 #x 0 0 0 0 0
 #y 0 0 0 0 0
 #x 0 0 0 0 0
```

#### data

```
m1 <-  structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
  0L, 0L), .Dim = c(3L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("x", "y", "x"), 
   c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")))

m2 <-  structure(c(1.2, 1.5, 1.4), .Dim = c(3L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
        c("a", "c", "e"), "y"))
```

Comment: "Error in mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) : 
  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length" gave an error like this. any other suggestion? thanks

Comment: m2<- structure(c(0.370815380378177, -0.528734132199295, 0.233384291636424, 
-0.0852907684698282, 0.366598187431862, -1.16214771847082, -0.0562426148494007, 
-1.46078290713205e-07, 0.113854254533139, 0.0156725376516465, 
-0.0182147777649396, 0.00417364233113778), .Dim = c(12L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("a", "c", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", 
    "j", "k", "l", "o", "r"), "m2"))

Comment: @user3525533 What about m1? Is it the same?

Comment: m1<- structure(c(0,0,0,0,.....), .Dim = c(21L, 
17L), .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c", .....)))

Comment: @user3525533 The colname of `m2` is `m2` in your dput output.  Also, please show the full output rather than `....` because it will not work.  Try to paste that into your console and you will get error.

Comment: so I don't have same column in both matrix, such as b column.

Comment: @user3525533 If there is no intersects between rownames and colnames, what would be your expected output?